# Local SSRS report slow initialization

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a Local SSRS report and setting parameters and data sources.

```
LocalReport Report = new LocalReport();
Report.ReportEmbeddedResource = "SomeReport.rdlc";
Report.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("ReportStartTime", StartTime.ToString()));
Report.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("ReportEndTime", EndTime.ToString()));
Report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ReportData", BuildReport()));
Report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ParametersData", BuildReportParameters()));
```

The problem I am seeing is that the first action after setting ReportEmbeddedResource is very slow. I am assuming that the system is loading the report resource and initializing it. However, my report is quite simple.

Should this loading take 5-10 seconds even before assigning any datasources?

Comment: How's your machine doing during that time - cpu pegged?

Comment: No machine usage during this time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I switched to Telerik reporting and now things are much better.